# How to get the tag relations results just by using SQL(s)?

Tags: sql, tagging, database-relations

```
Table tags:
article_id     tag
1              Language
1              Java
1              c++
2              Language
2              c++
3              c++
```

and how can I write SQL(s) query(s) to make the data like below:

```
Table tags_relations:

tag1        tag2     relations_degree
Language    C++     2
Language    Java    1
```

note: if the tag refers to the same article then the relations_degree + 1

The purpose of this approach is to calculate the relations between tags, can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT A.tag AS tag1, B.tag AS tag2, COUNT(*) as relations_degree
FROM tags A
     INNER JOIN tags B ON A.article_id = B.article_id
WHERE A.tag = 'Language' AND a.tag <> b.tag
GROUP BY A.tag, B.tag
ORDER BY B.tag ASC
```

Based on your example, I assumed you were limiting it to tag1 = 'Language', otherwise there's the case of tag1 = Java, tag2 = c++, relations_degree = 1.  To get that:

```
SELECT A.tag AS tag1, B.tag AS tag2, COUNT(*) as relations_degree
FROM tags A
     INNER JOIN tags B ON A.article_id = B.article_id
WHERE A.tag > b.tag
GROUP BY A.tag, B.tag
ORDER BY B.tag ASC
```

Comment: Thanks , it is sort of right. But can you explain if left join will be better or? Also what's the A.tag > B.tag does ? Thanks.

Comment: I added the a.tag > b.tag there to make results unique.  Otherwise, you'd have rows in the result set that look like "Language c++ 2" and later a "c++ Language 2", which I assume you don't want.  And in this case, the inner join will result in you only seeing results with relations_degree >= 1, whereas switching to a left join will show you rows like "Language NULL 1", which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have some sort of "Tag type", so that your set looks more like:

```
article_id   tag   tag_type
1            Java  Language
1            c++   Language
2            c++   Language
3            c++   Other
```

Then you could easily just use `COUNT(*)`, grouping by `tag_type` and `tag`.

Presuming (without trying to make a PRES out of U and ME) that you have a bunch of other tag_types, then I'm not sure how best to assign tag_types to tags, and you will probably find that easier than me. But this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the difficult here is to just find out the relations between the tags, so there do not have a tag_type for each tag. 'language','java' are the tags on one article.

Comment: Ah, ok... I misunderstood. I thought you were meaning "There's the language Java, and there's the language C++". So if Java and C++ appeared together on the same article, you'd want that to appear as well?

Comment: Yes, I know you c what I mean now.